# ssh-add with opensc failed

Tags: ssh-agent, yubikey, opensc

I'm setting up a Ubuntu 20.04 to visit servers that require PIV authentication. The command `ssh-add -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so` fails with:

```
Could not add card "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so": agent refused operation
```

Starting ssh agent used to work for this kind of error when adding an RSA key, but not this time. I tried combinations of killing/starting ssh agent, unplug/plug the yubikey, and none of them  worked.

What did I miss?